# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I want to include Asp.Net Identity into my app.

But when I want to register a new user, I get an error on javascript side:

**Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.**

This is the code in my **Controller**: When I click the button to register the user, I get in the function below.

```
$scope.signUp = function () {

     AuthenticationService.register($scope.registerData).then(function (response) {
        ...
      },
      function (response) {
         ...             
      });
  };
```

And this is the code in my **Service**, which is called in the Controller above.

```
     register: function (registerData) {            
        this.logout();
        Restangular.all('api/account/register').post(registerData);            
     }
```

What am I doing wron? Can you help me to get the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service method does not return the promise of what Resangular.all().post() is supposed to return. Its a q promise.

```
 register: function (registerData) {            
    this.logout();
    return Restangular.all('api/account/register').post(registerData);  
    //return $http.post("api/account/register", {data:registerData})
 }
```

Comment: Your welcome. If it worked for you I would appriciate if you mark it as "the answer to your problem @user3679607